# 3m unshielded 3V3 UART

Tags: digital-logic, uart, signal-integrity, emi-filtering

I have a product that probably uses the wrong digital interface, but I'm trying to make it work anyway. Differential signalling, a better cable and other things would be desirable, but that is outside of the design realm, unfortunately.

I have a 3.3V MCU and a 1.8V sensor that communicates UART @115k baud over a 3m cable. In between there is a level shifter to accommodate the different voltages.

I had a SI problem earlier because I used a non-buffering level shifter that was not enough to drive the signal over the long cable. Now I've swapped to a stronger one ([TXU0202](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txu0202.pdf)) and tried to improve the design otherwise. If anyone would care to give some feedback I am sure I would learn a ton.

Here is my schematic and my reasoning:
[image: Sch]

- D2, D5 - Protect MCU from ESD at the wire connector
- C1, C2 - decoupling for the level shifter power rails
- R1, R2 - Pull up
- R3 - prevent ringing and EMI due to high drive shifter with fast edges
- R4 - Hi-Z while powering up

The sensor comes with a dev kit, which uses a pull-up on the RX-pin, but it runs the MCU at 1.8V too, so there is no level shifter. I'm not sure re. pull-ups though. Should I not use them when I have a buffered level shifter? Should I put them on all 4 signal pins? Any other combination...

Should I try to prevent ringing on the short RX side as well (B1Y->p17)? Should I use ferrite beads instead/also? RC filters?

Perhaps I will have to measure this design and then adjust according to what I find, but what are relevant things to consider? RLC values between MCU and level shifter? Edge rate to determine relevant frequencies? Other things?

Comment: If you can add ferrite beads in line, you can also add a line driver; so, fix the issue instead of trying to make it marginally work :) Note that your use case is literally what RS232 was made for; TTL-to-full-RS232-levels converters are cheap.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but going 232 would mean I have to change things on the other end of the cable, which I can't do in this case.

The new level shifter features high drive strength (12mA @ 5V in the datasheet, although I'm running at 3.3). Isn't that what a line driver would add? Or am I missing something? @marcusmüller

Comment: yes, you'd also need a converter at the other end. Your strong driver only helps if you add strong termination at the receiving end! The mA rating tells you how much current it *can* source, given low enough impedance to sink it into.

Comment: I don't think you need differential signalling to send a 100kbit signal a few meters, but this is going to be hard if these are loose cables flapping around the room. What is stopping you from soldering in coax? That would make 3m trivial.

Comment: @marcusmüller Regardless of the termination it still help me overcome the capacitance of the cable?

Comment: @user1850479 The individual lines are not flapping about. They are part of a pre-purchased cable. An outer insulator, four inner insulators and four inner stranded copper wires that is.

Comment: @AlexanderOhm it's unlikely the capacitance is really a problem at these speeds; now, combine capacitance with noise and insufficient termination, and you have a problem.

Comment: @AlexanderOhm You likely need many different tricks and many hours tweaking the different tricks to make this work and even then it's still just an unreliable 3 meter 3.3V logic level connection at 115200 bps over an unshielded untwisted cable. It would likely be faster to get working if you add 3.3V RS232 transceivers to both ends of the cable so the logic level goes in the cables only for 10cm or so. And then the other end will have the level converter close to 3.3V transceiver and the 1V8 sensor. Please note even for current setup, you likely need the tweaks to both ends of the cable.

Comment: Nobody knows how much signal quality improvement is actually needed; look at oscilloscope traces.

Comment: Adding parallel capacitance or series inductance (ferrite beads or chokes) can reduce HF interference here. If the interference is very high, it'd be best if you can  decrease the baudrate and go agressive with the inductance/capacitance.